# replace part of string with html tags in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this string "Accept terms and conditions" and by design I need to replace part of that string with span tags, that is, "terms" and "conditions" should be wrapped with span like `<span>terms</span>` and `<span>conditions</span>`. To find solution I have found [How to add color to a specific part of a string in React using replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54562124/how-to-add-color-to-a-specific-part-of-a-string-in-react-using-replace) but it does not work as expected. So, I have FormInput component which is used like this:

```
<FormInput
          type="checkbox"
          value={formik.values.terms}
          name="terms"
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          label={`Accept terms and conditions`}
          checkbox={true}
        >
          {formik.touched.terms && formik.errors.terms ? (
            <ErrorMessage termsCheckbox={true}>
              {formik.errors.terms}
            </ErrorMessage>
          ) : null}
        </FormInput>
```

As you can see I am passing label={`Accept terms and conditions`} and I need to ensure that the words 'terms' and 'conditions' are in red color

Comment: Please post your code so we can get a better idea of how to help you.

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp, done, I have added react component I hope it is clearer now if not pls let me know

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the following approach can be followed.
you can use [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for this purpose. Find the match in your string and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) them with desired pattern using the result from respective capturing groups.

```js
var str = 'accept terms and conditions'
var regex = /(terms)|(conditions)/g

var res = str.replace(regex,function(match,p1,p2){
   if(p1) return `<span>${p1}</span>`
   else if (p2) return `<span>${p2}</span>`
})
console.log(res)
```